# HashMaps - Unclear on the hash function and double hashing

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable, double-hashing

I have been asked to implement a hash map using an array. I need to insert the following keys:

```
15, 7, 26, 39, 11, 9, 27, 5, 18, 2, 54, 22, 4
```

into an array of size 19 using the hash function:

```
(3x + 7) % 19
```

Using linear probing, I would expect to get the following array (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
Index:    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
Key:      4         11   5    18                       7    26   39   27   2    15   9    22   54
```

where 26 had a collision with 7 at index 9, and so was inserted at index 10, and 39 then had a collision with 26 at index 10 and so was inserted at index 11.

I am now attempting to insert the same elements in an array implementation of a HashMap, using double hashing instead of linear probing. The 2nd hash function I am given is:

```
11 - (x % 11)
```

I have two questions:

Does this mean that my array will be of size 11 or still 19?

Do I initially use the original hash function and if the given index is free, insert the element there, otherwise if there is a collision, use the 2nd hash function and insert the element there?

Comment: That's what I figured as I have just realised that there are more than 11 elements and so there would be plenty of collisions and at least one of these would be unavoidable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing) the secondary hash function is used indirectly in the probing function:

```
h(0, x) = (3x + 7) % 19
h(j, x) =  ((3x + 7) + j(11 - (x % 11))) % 19
```

Where j is the collision counter.